# Multitouch not working on 11.10

Tags: 11.10, thinkpad, multi-touch

I have a Thinkpad edge 520, installing drivers isn't possible because the site doesn't support Linux... My multitouch was working on a previous version of Ubuntu.
On top of that i have a problem with my keyboard (maybe also driver problem?) I can't press keys fast after each other (or the same key, which is quite annoying).
Anybody have any suggestions?

```
xinput list:
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint                     id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera                         id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xinput set-int-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Two-Finger Scrolling" 8 1
xinput set-int-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling" 8 1 1
xinput set-int-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure" 32 10
xinput set-int-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Two-Finger Width" 32 8
```

The above work for me. It is not persistent accross reboots, so I set up a script to enable multi touch every time Ubuntu boots

Comment: thanks, it works. 
Can you please also tell me how to make a script run at startup every time?

Answer (score 0):

Please show us you output for `xinput list`.

Otherwise did you try this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad

Comment: comment on end of the page:

I have the same problem. I can use vertical edge scrolling but not horizontal edge scrolling on my touchpad. The Ubuntu Forum points to your comment on this page for a debian package that'll fix this bug. It explicitly points to your comments #115 and #116. You mention the debian package is attached but there's nothign there and comment #116 is missing (which I'm guessing had the attached files to install).

Can you help me out and repots the bug fixer or can you direct me to where I can get this bug fixed? Thanks.

Comment: Try The Messie's solution, it should do the job. If not do `xinput list-props 10` and look for Two-Finger Scrolling.